# Problem after importing a module with its functions

Tags: python, import, opencv, orb

After importing `opencv-contrib-python` and `opencv-python` I can use its function i.e `cv2.imshow()`.

The problem is when I am creating an object `orb = cv2.ORB` or `cv2.ORB_create()` when I type `orb`, trying to get `detectandcompute` or any other function from `orb` (same happens with `sift`) it does not show any func recognized.

I am using a class inside my project and this only happens inside the class. Outside the class I noticed funcs are recognized.

```
dabi = np.array(self.coords[i], dtype=np.uint8)

kp = orb.detect(dabi,None)  #returns empty list

kp,des = orb.compute(dabi,kp)

keyps = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,img,color=(0,255,0))

plt.imshow(keyps),plt.show()
```

Comment: The code you provided does not actually correspond with the error you have mentioned.  Can you show us the full code and the full error, please?  Please also see how to post a [mcve].